# Ajustar un cuadro de datos a a una funcion

Tags: python, funciones

Estoy trabajando con multiples cuadros de datos que tienen la siguiente forma:

```
`dat = pd.DataFrame({'Y':[0.0455,0.079,0.059,0.144],'X':[0.055,0.110,0.165,0.220]})

`dat
Out[14]: 
    Y      X
0  0.0455  0.055
1  0.0790  0.110
2  0.0590  0.165
3  0.1440  0.220
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es ajustar estos pocos datos a una función de la forma: Y=kX**m (a la potencia m)

Lo unico que encuentro es'scipy.optimize.curve_fit' que requiere multiples rondas de simulación de datos y añadir ruido para determinar el mejor ajuste, pero me parece muy demandante para el pequeño numero de datos que estoy trabajando por cuadro de datos.

Es posible obtener los parametros 'k' y 'm' de una manera mas simple?

Usando un software comercial, ya se que  k = 0.4813 y m = 0.8935.
No puedo usar el software comercial porque tengo miles de esas pequeños cuadros de datos. Gracias por sus sugerencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903506/scipy-curve-fit-fails-power-law) (la parte después de la edición) proporciona un método. Nota que los parámetros (`k = -0.3176 y m = 0.8935.`) en la pregunta no coinciden con los datos. Tal vez son el resultado de otro cuadro de datos.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

dat = pd.DataFrame({'Y': [0.0455, 0.079, 0.059, 0.144], 'X': [0.055, 0.110, 0.165, 0.220]})

# logarimo de los datos
lx = np.log(dat.X)
ly = np.log(dat.Y)

def f(x, N, a):
    return N * x ** (-a)

def f_log(x, lN, a):
    return a * x + lN

popt_log, pcov_log = curve_fit(f_log, lx, ly)

xnew = np.linspace(min(dat.X), max(dat.X), 500)

plt.plot(dat.X, dat.Y, 'bo')  # datos originales
# plt.plot(xnew, f(xnew,  -0.3176, 0.8935), 'g', label='otro programa') # parametros del otro programa
plt.plot(xnew, f(xnew, np.exp(popt_log[0]), -popt_log[1]), 'r', label='scipy curve_fit')
print("k =", np.exp(popt_log[0]), "  m =", -popt_log[1]) # k = 0.2923   m = -0.6501
# plt.loglog() # para un plot logaritmico, la curva sera una linea recta
plt.show()
```

[image: ejemplo del plot]

Comment: Tienes razón, k=0.4813840 es el parámetro esperado, lo que exprese fue 10^k porque estaba aplicando logX y logY,  de cualquier forma la solución que propones es la que esperaba, solo con la modificación de `return N * x ** (m)` con 'm' positivo y llamando la función con `curve_fit(f, dat.X, dat.Y)` sin necesidad de convertir a logaritmo.